# l2 lambdas in Keras.regularizers

Tags: python, regularization, ridge-regression, keras

Is the value supplied to the shrinkage regularizers (l1 and l2) in Keras the inverse of the lambda coefficient?

e.g. `Dense(dense2, activation=softplus, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))` would indicate $\lambda$=100 ?

---

Given $\lambda$ in:
$loss = RSS + \lambda\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta^{2}_{i}$
Where $n$ = Number of coefficients, excluding the bias and $RSS$=residual sum of squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you [read the code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/regularizers.py), it shows that the argument to `regularizers.l2()` matches your definition of $\lambda$. `regularizers.l2()` is just an alias that calls `L1L2`.

```
class L1L2(Regularizer):
    """Regularizer for L1 and L2 regularization.
    # Arguments
        l1: Float; L1 regularization factor.
        l2: Float; L2 regularization factor.
    """

    def __init__(self, l1=0., l2=0.):
        self.l1 = K.cast_to_floatx(l1)
        self.l2 = K.cast_to_floatx(l2)

    def __call__(self, x):
        regularization = 0.
        if self.l1:
            regularization += self.l1 * K.sum(K.abs(x))
        if self.l2:
            regularization += self.l2 * K.sum(K.square(x))
        return regularization

    def get_config(self):
        return {'l1': float(self.l1),
                'l2': float(self.l2)}
```